# Updating an android application

Tags: android

I have made an android app. I want to upload it on android market. I later want to make updates too. So what necassary stepts should i take so that it automatically detects the android new version and download and install them

I have tried googling but no exact tutorial have been found.
In coding what links should I put and stuff like that.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Set this line to your manifest:

```
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">
```

-Increase the versionCode for each new version and update
-do NOT change the packagename of the app
-use the update functionality in your google play account

Answer (score 0):

when you upload new version app, upgrade its versionCode and versionName in Manifest.xml. Market will handle it automatically by reading the versionCode and notify user's device to upgrade if possible. Ensure that the new versionCode value must be bigger than the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update your manifest file, by changing the version code

```
 <manifest android:versionName="1.6" 
  android:versionCode="7"
```

If the version code has not increased, google will not let you upload the new version.

Once released, the user's google play account will detect new version, and if they have selected automatic update for the App, it will install for them.
If not then it will notify them of available update when they are next in their
'My Apps' section of google play.

Hope this helps